# How to set a BASE URL for sphinx documentation?

Tags: python-sphinx

I have created documentation for my project using sphinx. the current endpoint for my documentation is `/`. My question is, how can i make my documentation follow a `docs/<filename>` pattern?

```
EX. <app.url>/docs/index.html
```

in my `project`'s `config.py` i have:

```
DOCS_DIRECTORY = '/docs/'
```

Answer (score 2):

Add this line in `conf.py`：

```py
html_baseurl = '/docs/'
```

ref: [sphinx doc](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html)

Answer (score -1):

you should call `sphinx-build -b html sourcedir builddir`. See the Sphinx doc, page [First Steps with Sphinx](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/tutorial.html?highlight=docs_directory)

Comment: when my documentation is built i see it live at http://127.0.0.1:8000/index.html . what i want to see is http://127.0.0.1:8000/docs/index.html @humbalan

Comment: what did you input as builddir?